# how to make a discord bot edit a dm message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to implement a simple database for my server on Discord so i need my bot to DM me and when a variable change his value, he edit the DM (using the ID of the message he sent me) with the new value for the variables. (sorry my english)

That's what I've at the moment:

```
async function replyAndLog() {
    let sent = await msg.author.send("<database things>");
    let id = sent.id;
    console.log(id) //the id of the DM
}


//when i need to edit
if (msg.content === '!edit') {
    msg.id("id").edit("<new databese>") // here's the problem, i dont know how to write this line
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const User = client.users.cache.get("Your UserId");
if (!User.dmChannel) return console.log("No messages found.");

// Getting the message by ID
User.dmChannel.messages.fetch("MessageID").then(dmMessage => {
    // Editing the message.
    dmMessage.edit("I have an update!");
})
```

Comment: I couldn't implement this... always this happens ''ReferenceError: client is not defined''

Comment: Change `client` with your actual client variable. (`const variableName = new discord.Client();`)