# discord.js find and edit messages in dm

Tags: find, discord.js, message, edit

i'm trying to find message in dm and edit it via discord.js but i'm unable to do
my code:

```
const User = client.users.cache.get(usrid);
                    if (!User.dmChannel) return console.log("No messages found.");

                    // Getting the message by ID
                    User.dmChannel.messages.fetch(lastmsgid).then(dmMessage => {
                        // Editing the message.
                    dmMessage.edit(`${dmMessage.content}\n${messageToSend}`);
```

Error:

```
readline.js:1147
        throw err;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'dmChannel' of undefined
at C:\Users\Shankar\Desktop\bot\Disgd-hax\index.js:29:35
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:327:5)
at Interface._line (readline.js:658:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1003:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:205:10)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at emitKeys (internal/readline/utils.js:335:14)
at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
at ReadStream.onData (readline.js:1137:36)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: Are you sure `usrid` is spelled correctly and is not supposed to be `userid`? In the case that it is spelled correctly, how is it defined?

Comment: Where and how did you define `usrid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `usrid` is used correctly and is a user id, it mean that you are currently fetching the userid and getting user result not a dm channel or a dm message, to be able to do such that.

I suggest using the `messages.fetch` method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160056/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-edit-a-dm-message)